# Class Instances in Swift/Spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, oop, sprite-kit

I am a Swift noob and could really use some advice. I am trying to create a class that builds a block in my SpriteKit scene by passing a few paramters for size and color through to the class. The code builds and the blocks DO appear in the scene BUT by printing out the node tree, I can see I am getting an empty node/container wrapping my blocks (maybe from the two addChilds?!). I am guessing I am doing more than one thing wrong here and would really love to understand how to structure this cleaner.

In my scene:

```
for i in 1...4! {
    let block = Block(blockCount: i, blockSize: "Large", blocksColor: blocksColor)
    blocksContainer?.addChild(block)
}
```

And my class:

```
import SpriteKit

class Block: SKShapeNode {
    
    var block : SKSpriteNode?
    
    private var blockCount: Int
    private var blockSize: String
    private var blocksColor: UIColor

    init(blockCount: Int?, blockSize: String?, blocksColor: UIColor?) {
        
        self.blockCount = blockCount!
        self.blockSize = blockSize!
        self.blocksColor = blocksColor!
        
        super.init()
        
        var blockSizePixels: Int
        if (blockSize == "XLarge") {
            blockSizePixels = 232
        } else if (blockSize == "Large") {
            blockSizePixels = 152
        } else if (blockSize == "Medium") {
            blockSizePixels = 104
        } else if (blockSize == "Small") {
            blockSizePixels = 56
        } else {
            blockSizePixels = 32
        }
        
        //build block
        block = SKSpriteNode(color: blocksColor!, size: CGSize(width: blockSizePixels, height: blockSizePixels))
        block!.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: blockSizePixels, height: blockSizePixels))
        block!.position = CGPoint(x: Int.random(in: -100...100), y: 300)
        block!.physicsBody!.friction = 0.05
        block!.physicsBody!.restitution = 0.6
        block!.physicsBody!.mass = 1.0
        block!.name = "block" + String(self.blockCount)
        self.addChild(block!)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

And my node tree print out comes out as:

```
Optional("blocksContainer")
nil <- empty node
Optional("block1")
nil
Optional("block2")
nil
Optional("block3")
nil
Optional("block4")
```

Comment: Get rid of the `block` property and use `self`; your `Block` class is already a node (because it subclasses `SKShapeNode`). Also, use an `enum` for your block size,  not strings

Comment: Ah thanks @Paulw11 I did try that but I am not sure how to handle this line: 

self.SKSpriteNode(color: blocksColor!, size: CGSize(width: blockSizePixels, height: blockSizePixels))

That errors: Value of type 'Block' has no member 'SKSpriteNode'

Comment: You don't need that line. That was how you were creating a child `SKSpriteNode`.  You can just set `self.size` and `self.color`

Comment: The whole universe opened up - thank you @Paulw11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from @Paulw11 I refactored my class to be the following... taking out the multiple sprites and replacing them with a path. Nice!

```
import SpriteKit

class Block: SKShapeNode {
    
    private var blockCount: Int
    private var blockSize: String
    private var blocksColor: UIColor

    init(blockCount: Int?, blockSize: String?, blocksColor: UIColor?) {
        
        self.blockCount = blockCount!
        self.blockSize = blockSize!
        self.blocksColor = blocksColor!
        
        super.init()
        
        //isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        
        var blockSizePixels: Int
        if (blockSize == "XLarge") {
            blockSizePixels = XLarge
        } else if (blockSize == "Large") {
            blockSizePixels = Large
        } else if (blockSize == "Medium") {
            blockSizePixels = Medium
        } else if (blockSize == "Small") {
            blockSizePixels = Small
        } else {
            blockSizePixels = Tiny
        }
        
        //build block
        self.path = CGPath(rect: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: -blockSizePixels/2, y: -blockSizePixels/2), size: CGSize(width: blockSizePixels, height: blockSizePixels)), transform: nil)
        self.fillColor = blocksColor!
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: blockSizePixels, height: blockSizePixels))
        self.position = CGPoint(x: Int.random(in: -100...100), y: 300)
        self.physicsBody!.friction = 0.05
        self.physicsBody!.restitution = 0.6
        self.physicsBody!.mass = 1.0
        self.name = "block" + String(self.blockCount)

    }
    
    class func classMethod() {
        print ("hello from the class method")
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```